# How to get value INPUT.Text in one xaml and refer to it in another xaml?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, input, android-edittext

I have an EditText in my `MainActivity.cs`:

```
reqinput = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.rinput);
string r = rinput.Text
```

What I want is that in my other page, `Page1.cs`, I can refer to `r` (the text in rinput). How do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if page1.cs is next activity than you can pass string with intent you created.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,typeof(page1));
intent.putExtras(key,value);
Startactivity(intent);
```

and get this value on page1.cs using

```
var out=Intent.GetStringExtra(key);
```

if page1 is normal class file than public property will be usefull.